# Getting only first value in List() with static But full value with out static method

Tags: php, static, non-static

In my display() method setting value using static initPost() and getting all value using static getAll and a single value using static get('email') method.When I'm checking using var_dump() everything is fine.I want to take my value in my list().But I'm getting only first string of each value.But when I do it with out static method getting full value in my list().What is the problem?

```
public function display()
{
    echo "<pre>";
    Form::initPost());//initializing value
    var_dump(Form::getAll());//Getting all value
    var_dump(Form::get('email'));//getting only email value

    list($name,$email,$pass,$rpass,$phone)=Form::getAll();//taking value to list

    var_dump($name);//Here is the problem .only getting first string from full name
}
```

This is My form class:

```
 class Form
{

private static $value = array();
public static function initPost()
{
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    self::$value[$key] = $value;
}
public static function getAll()
{
    return self::$value;
} 

public static function get($value){

        self::$value = $_POST[$value];

    return self::$value;
}

}
```

//This is OUTPUT section

```
var_dump(Form::getAll());//Getting all value
array(5) {
["name"]=>
string(12) "Bristi Bella"
["email"]=>
string(16) "bristi@gmail.com"
["pass"]=>
string(6) "123456"
["rpass"]=>
 string(6) "123456"
["phone"]=>
 string(6) "123456"
}

//Getting email value
var_dump(Form::get('email'));
string(16) "bristi@gmail.com"
 var_dump($name);//only getting first string from full name.But want full name
 string(1) "b"
```

Comment: what is the difference between `var_dump` of static and non-static Form->getAll()

Comment: I don't understand your question @Raheeel

Comment: Post the code for your Form

Comment: do a `var_dump(Form::getAll());` and paste it in the question.

Comment: You are overwriting `Form::$value` in your `Form::get()` Method so all what you have done in `Form::initPost()` will be gone.

Comment: Where is the "not-static" part of your question?

Comment: I've tried your both solution.It's giving me Undefined offset :4 3 2 1 0 on my list() @steven

Comment: I've delete it. I've to do it static way @IkoTikashi

Comment: As for the Undefined offset: you need to make sure that there actually are $_POST values to be inserted in your $value.

Comment: How can I check   that there actually are $_POST values are inserted in my $value. – @ IkoTikashi

Answer (score 0):

The descripted happens because by calling `get('email')` you have killed your $values array and set it to a string with the email field from your post request. By calling the `list()` on a string it puts each char of the string in your list. And by echoing the first item of your list you will get the first char.

You should not overwrite your Form::$value in your get method.
fetch instead the array key from your Form::$value like this:

```
public static function get($value){

    return array_key_exists($value,self::$value) ? self::$value[$value] : false;
}
```

or at least set only the requested index like this:

```
public static function get($value){

    self::$value[$value] = $_POST[$value];

    return self::$value[$value];
}
```

And you should not fetch the variables by using list(). Please do it like this:

```
$name = Form::get('name');
$email = Form::get('email');
$pass = Form::get('pass');
$rpass = Form::get('rpass');
$phone = Form::get('phone');
```

Or simply do:

```
$all = Form::getAll();
echo $all['email'];
echo $all['phone']; // and so on
```

Comment: I've tried your both solution.It's giving me Undefined offset :4 3 2 1 0 on my list() @steven

Comment: be careful with list. I recommend to fetch each field via `Form::get()` instead of using list(). Like descipted here http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.

Comment: I dont get it.I'm already fetching my value using Form:get() but I need to store my value in some other array.

Comment: list is used to extract fields from an array. You tried to extract your fields from the array which is returned by `getAll()` which is an associative array with non numerical indices. Thats the reason for failing.

Comment: Ok Then can you please write a solution for me @steven

Answer (score 0):

Probably this helps

```
class Form  {

  private static $value = array();

  public static function initPost($expectValues = false){

      if($expectValues && !count($_POST)){
          throw new \Exception ("POST does not have any values");
      }
      self::$value = $_POST;
  }

  /**
    * use get() to grab all the values or get('key') to grab selected     
    *  value
    * @return mixed|array
    * @throws \Exception
   **/

  public static function get($value = null){

    if($value === null){
        return self::$value;
    }

    if(!array_key_exists($value,self::$value){
        throw new \Exception ("Could not find $value");
    }

    return self::$value[$value];
 }

 public function getByPosition($position){
     return implode(array_slice($array, $position, 1));
 }

}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution.It's also giving me Undefined offset :4 3 2 1 0 on my list() @Rx Seven

Comment: I have updated my solution , Thought you wanted to get the value searched by the key ... If you want to get the 0th element you can now use getByPosition(0) to get the first element of array. In case the element is not there in the array it will return empty string("").